# Monthly statistics based on raster file name

Tags: arcpy, iterator, wildcard

I have a raster of a national park in Norway showing the temperature every day between the 1st of November 1999 and the 31st March 2015. I have created booleon images showing which pixels are above zero and which are below zero. I now want to go through the folder and sum up how many times each pixel has a temperature above zero each month. The file format is rr_YYYY_MM_DD.tif I tried adapting a script I found here (https://geonet.esri.com/thread/70044) to do this based on the file name, but I get the error message

"[function] + Utils.flattenLists(in_rasters_or_constants))"

when I try to run it.

The code is below.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
arcpy.env.workspace = r"G:\Hardangervidda\Suitable pixels\Precipitation_3mm"
outWks = r"G:\Hardangervidda\Suitable pixels\monthly_stats"
for year in range(1999,2015):  # 1999 through 2015
    for month in range(13):      # 1 to 12
        # wildcard - "rr_YYYY_MM*.tif" (format month 1 -> "01")
        wild = "rr_{0}_{1:02d}*.tif".format(year,month)
        rasList = arcpy.ListRasters(wild) # list all rasters for a month
        outRas = arcpy.sa.CellStatistics(rasList,"SUM") # monthly mean
        outPath = outWks + "/" + "m{0}m{1:02d}".format(year,month)
        outRas.save(outPath)
```

Comment: Why you use "SUM" in the CellStatistics function instead of "MEAN"?

Comment: It is the sum that I want, but thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've just run

```
for month in range(13):
print month
```

and the output starts in 0 up to 12, then your ListRaster contains no raster. It's empty. I believe that's why the CellStatistics function crashes. If you change that to

```
for month in range(1,13):
```

will run ok.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I get the same error message about the lists.

Comment: Do you mind checking the rasList content just before in goes in to the CellStatistics line?
You can add this line:
arcpy.AddMessage([x for x in rasList]

Comment: When I do "print rasList" I see that it is empty. Maybe the wildcard is incorrect? I do not understand the format function with the {1:02d}.

Comment: That format is working as expected. That {1:02d} returns the parameter in the position 1 (remember parameters here starts on 0), as two spaces reserved, and show just decimals 'd'

Comment: Hi @user3652893 ... Did this work?

Comment: No problem. Do you mind marking my answer as best answer to your question? I'm trying to boost my reputation score, and is just part of how things work here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your wildcard many not be working as expected.
Instead of

```
wild = "rr_{0}_{1:02d}*.tif".format(year,month)
```

try this:

```
wild = "rr_{0}_{1:02d}_??.tif".format(year,month)
```